# Linear system with different units/dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a system of linear equations with a block structure

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
\underline{\underline{A}} \\
\underline{\underline{A}}^\prime
\end{pmatrix}
\underline{x} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\underline{b} \\
\underline{b}^\prime
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

The problem is that the blocks with and without primes have different physical units, and because of this they also have different orders of magnitude (physically the orders of magnitude are not comparable, but numerically they are), which makes the numeric solution unstable (the system is overdetermined, I minimize the residual). However $\underline{x}$ is just one vector that is the same for both blocks.

Is there a formalism (maybe involving tensors?) to solve two coupled linear systems?

Comment: Is $\underline{x}$ scalar ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with scalar? It is a real valued coefficient vector; each element of the vector is scalar, if that is what you mean.

Comment: Can't you rescale one of the blocks to get more comparable magnitudes ?

Comment: I tried that, but the outcome varies wildly and is physically unreasonable. It's basically a multiobjective problem and I'm somewhat afraid there is no unique solution to it.

Comment: Is your solver reliable ?

Comment: I perform SVD then I cut off singular values below a certain threshold $\delta$ when calculating the pseudoinverse
\begin{equation}
\Sigma^\dagger_{ii} = \begin{cases} 1/\Sigma_{ii}, \Sigma_{ii} > \delta \\
0, \Sigma_{ii}<\delta \end{cases}
\end{equation}

It is robust in the sense that it never crashes or produces unreasonably huge values, but I am discarding information.

Comment: What's the condition number ?

Comment: Depends on the particular physical system, but can go up to 1.0e20 (and probably beyond, I've just never had that case yet)